# Power BI :: change background color based on another column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I previously asked a question about how to use [PREVIOUSMONTH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75182919/previousmonth-returns-blank-rows-or-wrong-data)   and thanks to that I was able to create 2 columns:

- first one with the current month spending per resource on Azure
- second one with the same resources on the previous month:

[image]

I now would like to change the background color so the number could be:

- **Red ** if the cost has increased
- **Green ** if the cost has decreased
- **Yellow ** if the price is the same

Like this:

[image]

I checked into *Conditional Formatting > Background Color* but I think there is no option for doing that.

So I created this DAX rule:

```
PreviousMonthCheck = 
IF ([PreviousMonth] < MAX('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]),1,
    IF ([PreviousMonth] = MAX('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]),2,
        IF ([PreviousMonth] > MAX('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]),3,
            "Fourth case"
        )
    )
)
```

Now, how to use this rule to color the SelectedMonth?

Or is there any Visual that could do that out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can do it with native visuals. In the custom formatting, choose Rules and then reference your measure. Add the 3 rules as below.

BTW, your measure can and should be simplified using the SWITCH(TRUE()) pattern.

[image]

Comment: I did it, thank you David